# How to access NServiceBus dependency injection container?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5

I'm using NServiceBus 5's default dependency injection features. I want to register a singleton that depends on IBus in the endpoint config.

Ex:

```cs
configuration.RegisterComponents(r =>
{
  r.RegisterSingleton(new MyDependency(resolveIBus()));
  ...
}
```

How can I resolve the instance of IBus in the above pseduo code using NServiceBus's out-of-the-box dependency injection?

Comment: `configureComponents.ConfigureComponent<MyDependency>(DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance)` and `IBus` will be injected into you `MyDependency`

Comment: What @tchelidze said. The `IBus` implementation already registered on the container and can just be injected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```cs
configuration.RegisterComponents(r =>
{
  r.ConfigureComponent<MyDependency>(DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance);
  ...
}
```

The dependency mechanism will investigate the constructor(s) of the MyDependency type and chooses the simplest one it can completely resolve.  So, you'll need to create your `MyDependency` type like this:

```cs
public class MyDependency
{
  public MyDependency(IBus bus)
  {
  }
}
```

More information in the [NServiceBus Documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/dependency-injection/?version=core_5)

If you only know what type of service you need at runtime, you can use the `IServiceProvider` service like this:

```cs
public class MyDependency
{ 
  public MyDependency(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  { 
    ...
    var myService = (IMyService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMyService));
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This does help me achieve what I want to do, but I am curious if there is any way to retrieve the configured component. Other IOC tools I have used normally have a `container.Resolve` method of some sort that will get the configured object

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the dependency mechanism that is built-in in NServiceBus, but the documentation link that I provided also explains how to configure NServiceBus to use the IOC that you know.

Comment: Another way to achieve what you want is to use the `IServiceProvider` service like this:
    public class MyDependency  
    {  
       public MyDependency(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)  
       {  
          var myService = (IMyService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMyService));  
       }  
    }

Comment: I think that completely answers it. Mind adding that to your answer?

Comment: I extended my answer with an IServiceProvider example...

Comment: @MarcSelis using a service locator is generally considered a bad practice, so i wouldn't advertise it. [ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: @tchelidze I am aware of that and I try to avoid it as much as possible, but there are use cases (most of the times in framework-like code) where you only know what service type you need at runtime and then you have no other possibility than to use `IServiceProvider`or `IServiceLocator` or the likes...